# How can I inherit more than once from a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Following the instructions from [numpy's documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.subclassing.html), I am trying to inherit from np.ndarray. I can create a subclass of np.ndarray, but can't figure out how to inherit from that subclass again. It seems like the recommended viewcasting approach doesn't preserve attributes from the intermediate subclass:

```
import numpy as np


class Dataset(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, points: int):
        dataset = np.zeros(points).view(Dataset)
        dataset._points = points
        return dataset

    def average(self) -> float:
        return sum(self) / self._points


class OrderedDataset(Dataset):

    def __new__(cls, points: int):
        return Dataset(points).view(OrderedDataset)

    def check_order(self):
        for i in range(1, len(self)):
            assert self[i] >= self[i - 1]


def test():
    d = Dataset(100)
    assert np.allclose(d.average(), 0)

    od = OrderedDataset(100)
    od.check_order()
    assert np.allclose(od.average(), 0)  # Error: 'OrderedDataset' object has no attribute '_points'
```

This is the simplest minimal example I can think of, it is more useful to do this subclassing in my actual use case. Note that the OrderedDataset object is aware that it has an average() method, but not that it has a _points attribute. Any ideas how I could get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `super().__new__` instead of creating `Dataset` instance in `OrderedDataset` and change `np.zeros(points).view(Dataset)` to `np.zeros(points).view(cls)`

```
class Dataset(np.ndarray):

def __new__(cls, points: int):
    dataset = np.zeros(points).view(cls)
    dataset._points = points
    return dataset


class OrderedDataset(Dataset):

    def __new__(cls, points: int):
        return super().__new__(cls, points)
```

Another option is to add `__array_finalize__` to `Dataset` as suggested in the examples in the docs you linked

```
class Dataset(np.ndarray):

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None:
            return
        self._points = getattr(obj, '_points', None)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the first option doesn't work - the resulting object is of Dataset type, and so doesn't have access to the check_order method. The second method works. However, in my use case, I have quite a few attributes at each level of inheritance, so having to re-assign each of them in the __array_finalize__ method seems cumbersome.

Comment: @Miicck sorry, in the first example you also need to change to `dataset = np.zeros(points).view(cls)` in `Dataset`.

Comment: Just to note, the overridden __new__ method in OrderedDataset is not needed in this example - it does the same thing as the base class. Nonetheless, it's good to see how implementation-specific initialisation would be added to the OrderedDataset class.